# Getting string between a character and a symbol, without caring about what follows the symbol

Tags: python, string, file, directory, substring

In order to order some files into folders, I have to get the number (as if it was some sort of ID) of both folders (named as p.X, p. fixed, being X a number that can range from 1 to 200150) and files (being PX_N.gmspr, where P is fixed, X is the ID number of the folder and N an identifier of the file, which can be 2,3,6,8,9,A and H).

An example would be p.24 and P24_2.gmspr, P24_3.gmspr, P24_6.gmspr, P24_8.gmspr, P24_9.gmspr, P24_A.gmspr and P24_H.gmspr, in order to move all P24_N.gmspr to p.24

The PX_N.gmspr files are in a different folder than the target folders p.X . A little of os.chdir and  os.rename and the files can be moved easily so I believe that is not a problem.

What I want is to obtain the X number of the filename to compare with the folder number, forgetting about both the P and the _N.gmspr string.
Whereas I can obtain the folder number via
`foldername.split(".",1)[1]` I don't really know how to do it for the file number.

To sum up, I want to move some files called PX_N.gmspr to another folder identified almost the same p.X

Any idea? Thank you!!!

EDIT:
Regarding the answer given, I have to clarify myself about what I am trying to do, specially with the file and folder format:

```
Mother folder
├── Unclassified
│   └── All PX_N.gmspr being PX certain files that gotta be moved to another folders, X a number that ranges from 1 to 200150 (but not exactly 200150, is just a number ID) and N can be only 2, 3, 6, 9, A or H, nothing more. In total 15435 elements with each of the X having one of the 6 possibles N gmspr.
├──First Folder
│   └── p.X folders (X from 1 to 151), the aim is to select all the PX_N.gmspr files that agree with the X number that matches the p.X of the folder and move it to each folder.
├──Second Folder
│   └── p.X folders (X from 152 to 251, plus p.602 to p.628, p.823, p.824, 
│         p.825, p.881 and p.882)
└──Third Folder
    └── p.X folders (X from 252 to 386, plus p.585, p.586 and p. 587)
```

There are some other folders in order to order some more of the 15435 files.
I am currently searching about regex; unluckily for me, it is the first time I actually have to use them.

EDIT CAUSE SOLVED: SO THE POINT WAS TO PLAY WITH REGEX AND GETTING ONLY THE NUMBERS, BUT THEN AS NESTED LISTS APPEARED, ONLY THE FIRST NUMBER WAS USEFUL

Comment:  https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 1):

This is the perfect job for regexes.

First, let's create a temporary dir and fill it with some files to demonstrate.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from random import choices, randint
from string import ascii_letters

from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory

tmpdir = TemporaryDirectory()

for i in range(4):
    n = randint(1, 999)
    for i in range(randint(1, 5)):
        Path(
            tmpdir.name, f"P{n}.{''.join(choices(ascii_letters, k=10))}"
        ).touch()
```

Now we have 4 types of file (PN.), with between 1 and 5 files in this type.

Then, we just need to iterate through those file, extract the N from the file name with the regex [`P(\d+)\..+`](https://regex101.com/r/BmYlBe/1), and finally create destination dir and move the file.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import re

dir_re = re.compile(r"P(\d+)\..+")

for filepath in Path(tmpdir.name).iterdir():
    m = dir_re.match(filepath.name)
    dirpath = filepath.parent / f"p.{m.group(1)}"
    if not dirpath.is_dir():
        dirpath.mkdir()
    filepath.rename(dirpath / filepath.name)
```

For instance, from a flat temp directory, we have now the following sorted.

```
/var/folders/lf/z7ftpkws0vn7svq8n212czm40000gn/T/tmppve5_m1u/
├── p.413
│   └── P413.yJvxPtuzfz
├── p.705
│   ├── P705.DbwPyiFxum
│   ├── P705.FVwMuSqFms
│   ├── P705.PZyGIQEqSG
│   ├── P705.baRrkcNaZR
│   └── P705.tZKFTKwDah
├── p.794
│   ├── P794.CQTBgXOckQ
│   ├── P794.JNoKsUtgRU
│   └── P794.iSdrdohKYq
└── p.894
    └── P894.XbzFxnqYOY
```

And finally, cleanup the temporary directory.

```py
tmpdir.cleanup()
```

Comment: It may be what I need. It may be easier as the file extension is *.gmspr for all of them.

Comment: This will work with any extension, but you can also use [`Path.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) with `*.gmspr` and amend the regex to only match those at the end.